# Input and Output Iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a practice question concerning using input and output iterators. The heading of the function is as follows

```
template<class InpIter,class OutpIter>
OutpIter my_unique_copy(InpIter first, InpIter last, OutpIter result)
```

The function should copy the elements from the range [first,last] to result. In a consecutive group of duplicate elements, only the first value is copied. The return value is the end of the range to which the elements are copied.
Complexity:linear

I have an idea what to do just was wondering for a little help since I'm not that comfortable with iterators yet

```
template<class InpIter,class OutpIter>
OutpIter my_unique_copy(InpIter first, InpIter last, OutpIter result){
    InpIter current=first;
    first++;//point to second element
    while(first!=last){
        while(*first==*current){//Keep comparing elements to current to see if they're same
            first++;
        }
        result=current;
        current=first;
        result++;
        first++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok, what's the question? :)

Comment: Compilers don't bite... the only way to get comfortable is to give it a try.

Comment: You can also use `unique_copy()`

Comment: It doesn't work if `first == last`

Comment: It also doesn't write through the output iterator, `result`,  which is somewhat the point, isn't it?

Comment: ya the point of the exam question is to write out the code for it. I'm just debating whether i'll iterate off the container of elements. I only have like a half hour before the exam so i didn't wanna risk fooling around on the compiler

Comment: @whozCraig So instead of result=current, to write to result wouldn't it be *result=*current;

Comment: @JoshHamet something like that. there's some logic in this that is extraneous, and some limiting. john already pointed out one specific issue, an empty sequence will not work. The result assignment not withstanding, you have all the code here, too much in fact. If no one beats me too it I'll throw up something that shows you what I mean.

Comment: ya i figured i should have had a base case in case an empty sequence

Comment: You can, or simply account for it by not using `*first` until you know its a valid dereferencable iterator. Anyway, I posted something that shows one way to do this. Hopefully you get something out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were going for, with explanation at each step.

```
template<class InpIter,class OutpIter>
OutpIter my_unique_copy(InpIter first, InpIter last, OutpIter result)
{
    // keep going until end of sequence
    while(first!=last)
    {
        // save current position.
        InpIter current=first;

        // advance first, test it against last, and if not
        // equal, test what it references against current.
        // repeat this until *first != *current, or first == last
        while (++first != last && *first == *current);

        // not matter what dropped the loop above, we still have
        // our current, so save it off and advance result.
        *result++ = *current;
    }

    // not sure why you want to return the first iterator position
    // *past* the last insertion, but I kept this as-is regardless.
    return result;
}
```

I hope that explains it. (I don't think I missed anything, but I'm sure I'll hear it if I did.)

A very simple test harness:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int ar[] = { 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,8 };
    int res[10] = {0};

    int *p = my_unique_copy(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), res);
    std::copy(res, p, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: awesome! i wasn't sure about the return but that's what the spec made it sound like. Last thing, inside the while loop im guessing we would increment first until it either doesn't equal current anymore meaning we can store current and start from the next different value

Comment: Not sure I followed that last-thing. I tried to explain how the inner-while-loop logic works. it uses boolean-short-circuit evaluation to *not* deference `first` unless we know it isn't `last` yet. the exact order is 1. increment `first`, 2. check to see if it is `last`, if it is, break. 3. check to see if `*first == *current`, if they're not equal, break. otherwise go back to 1. Hope that made sense.

Comment: And if you're wondering how this works without resetting `current` to first after we save off `*result`, ask yourself what would be saving it as? We would be doing this: `current = first`. but thats exactly what the code *above* the inner-while-loop does. And its about to be executed again (unless `first == last`).

Comment: really cleared up some things for me, thanks alot